# What does the pipe/veritcal bar character mean in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Google-fu is failing me on this one. Can anyone briefly explain what the following statement would do?:

```
UPDATE
    message WITH (ROWLOCK)
SET
    message = message | 2
```

I found this in a trigger, and I am unable to find docs explaining what the | character does in a statement like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is a bitwise OR

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I had assumed message was a text field, which is why it confused me. If I had actually checked the underlying type, that would have made more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's the bitwise OR operator. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx). Effectively, `message` is a bitfield, and by bitwise-ORing it with 2, you're setting the second bit. See [Wikipedia's bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) article for a good overview of bit-twiddling :)

Answer (score 2):

| is a bitwise OR in T-SQL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186714.aspx

So if message contained 0, it would contain 2, if it contained 1, it would contain 3, etc.